# QThreadPool pure virtual method called

Tags: c++, qt

В конструкторе окна создаю объект Runnable:

```
testTask = new TestTask();
testTask->setAutoDelete(true);
connect(testTask, &TestTask::endTest, this, &MainWindow::endTest);
```

По нажатию кнопки запускаю:

```
void MainWindow::runTest()
{
    // Если тест не запущен, то запускаем.
    if (!testRunning)
    {
        bool startedTest = QThreadPool::globalInstance()->tryStart(testTask);

        if (!startedTest)
        {
            syslog("Тест не был запущен, нет свободных потоков", E);
        }
        else
        {
            testRunning = true; // помечаем, что тест уже запущен
            syslog("Тест запущен", I);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        syslog("Тест уже выполняется, ожидайте", E);
    }
}
```

При получении сигнала о завершении теста:

```
void MainWindow::endTest()
{
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone(); // нужно ли?
    testRunning = false; // помечаем, что тест уже окончен
    syslog("Тест окончен", I);
}
```

Код таска:

```
void TestTask::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Hello world from thread" << QThread::currentThread();

    // имитация работы процесса
    QThread::sleep (5);
    emit endTest(); 
}
```

Результат:

```
"Тест запущен"
Hello world from thread QThread(0x274c4338, name = "Thread (pooled)")    
"Тест окончен"
```

После повторного нажатия кнопки, после первого окончания теста,  получаю

```
"Тест запущен" 
pure virtual method called
```

И программа падает.
Если создание объекта Runnable помещаю в слот нажатия кнопки, то все работает хорошо. Т.е. При каждом нажатии кнопки новый объект, и у него запускается run.
Но ведь в документации сказано, что tryStart может быть вызвано многократно у того же Runnable.

Comment: А Вы в debug можете посмотреть стек обратных вызовов при падении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ж сами указали `testTask->setAutoDelete(true);` После выполнения таска - `QThreadPool` его удалил, и при повторной попытке запустить выполнение,

```
bool startedTest = QThreadPool::globalInstance()->tryStart(testTask);
```

`testTask` - уже удален и указывает в мусор.

Выхода два:

1. `testTask->setAutoDelete(false);`, но тогда не забыть в деструкторе его удалить самому.
2. При нажатие кнопки, каждый раз создавать новый `TestTask`

P.S. в документации не нашел указания на то, что `tryStart` можно многократно вызывать.

Comment: Вот и я подумал, что так. AutoDelete по умолчанию не false? Если не указывать `testTask->setAutoDelete(true);`, то происходит ровно то же. Создавть новый объект при нажатии кнопки - нормально?

Comment: Это не просто нормально, а так и надо делать. Тем более если Вам понадобится, чтоб запускалось сразу два или более ``TestTask``, тогда это единственный вариант, для каждого потока свой ``TestTask``